# Charger CN3722 does not terminate charging

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, solar-charge-controller

**Update:**

R7 is fix inserted by the manufacturer and is always 14k.
R6 has to be changed according to the manufacturer to 5.76K if a 2 cell Li-Ion is charged at 8.4V.
The manufacturer even supplies the different resistors in the package. 3.3k for 3 cell at 12.6V and 19.1k for 1 cell at 4.2V. I will have to measure the Batt V and the FB V. I will let you know a.s.a.p.
I have now the required values
[image]
**__________________________**

I am using a solar charging module working on a CN3722
[Overview](http://www.consonance-elec.com/seriesCN3722-E.html).       ..... [Datasheet](http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN3722.pdf) ..... [Application note](http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/Application/CN3701_02_03_04_E/Quick%20Start%20of%20CN37XX%20Demo%20Board.pdf)

Typical circuit: (Diagram changed - previous one incorrect!)

[image]

I am charging a 2 cell Li-Ion battery.
R6 between FB and GND is 5.76k for 8.4V.
MPPT is set to attempt to drive Vin to 10.5V.
I am using a 12V, 2A Power supply as power source.

The charging cycle looks normal with a constant voltage and initially 1.2A charging current which is reduced over time according to the Li-Ion charging curve. So far so good.
If the charging current reaches 9.5% of the max charging current, according to the data sheet, the charging should stop.
Unfortunately it does not stop and the LED "done" is not coming on.

The charging continues all the way until the charging current is zero. Even then the "done" LED is not coming on but the "charging" LED is still on.
If I then disconnect the power supply momentarily the "done" LED is illuminating and the charging cycle stops.

Does anybody have the same experience or have any idea what the cause for this behavior might be?

The diagram shown under the link "Datasheet" is how the circuit is.
The voltage divider R8/R3 is set to give 1.04V at Pin 7 (MPPT) if the **Input** voltage is 10.5V.

R6 is 5.76K. This is according to the data sheet correct for a 2 cell Li-Ion battery.

I bought this assembled module from
https://www.electrodragon.com/product/1-3-series-lithium-lilifepo4-battery-charger/

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a schematic or draw one with the tool (edit)

Comment: A link to the datasheet saves N others having to look for it. And a circuit diagram as part of your questionb is highly desirable. Even people without experience of the specific IC may have useful insights .

Comment: PLease advise ANY differences between your actual circuit and diagram above. Are you using a premade module? More information ................................ ?

Comment: You need to tell us the value of R7 and the voltage at VBat and pin 10 / FB when the charger transitions to constant voltage mode. || It seems quiote likely that your ratio of R7:R6 is wrong.  For V_CV = 8.4 V, R7 should be 11.9 k || 5.76 x (7.4-2.416)/2.416

Comment: For interest, what country are you in?

Comment: Do you solve the problem?
Can you share solution pls

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Do not know the reason for the fault. It looks like some of the boards work perfectly others don't. It is hit and miss. I replaced the faulty board with another one.